# create aws sagemker endpoint with lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I created an endpoint in `aws sagemaker` and it works well, I created a `lambda` function(`python3.6`) that takes files from `S3`, invoke the endpoint and then put the output in a file in `S3`.

I wonder if I can create the endpoint at every event(a file uploaded in an `s3 bucket)` and then delete the endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can Using `S3` event notification for object-created and call a `lambda` for creating endpoint for `sagemaker`.

This example shows how to make `object-created event trigger lambda`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

You can use `python sdk` to create endpoint for `sagemaker`

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint

But it might be slow for creating endpoint so you may be need to wait.

Comment: I agree, Lambdas timeout after 5 mins. so if it seems like it's going to be an issue you can have the "Create Endpoint" lambda terminate after executing that line of code and have a second lambda with a trigger event of a _CloudWatch notification that the endpoint has been successfully created_. The second lambda would run then run the inference by calling that endpoint and clean up by deleting it after. 

Deleting Sagemaker endpoints with boto3 can be found [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_endpoint)